# This is a solution to the simplest knapsack problem but the result weight always exceeds the permitted amount

Tags: python, optimization, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to fix this for a whole night but still the program doesn't work, and I felt like there's nothing wrong with it. The list taken is responsible for recording the objects that's being carried with the knapsack.

These are the most essential part of code that I wrote.

```
knapsack = [[0 for i in range(itemCount)] for j in range(capacity)]

    for i in range(itemCount):
        for j in range(capacity):
            if weights[i] <= j+1:
                knapsack[j][i] = max(knapsack[j][i-1], knapsack[j-weights[i]][i-1]+values[i])
            else:
                knapsack[j][i] = knapsack[j][i-1]
        if knapsack[capacity-1][i] == knapsack[capacity-1][i-1]:
            taken[i] = 0
        else:
            taken[i] = 1
    
    result = knapsack[capacity-1][itemCount-1]
```

Comment: I suspect you need to make the knapsack one longer in both dimensions, and look at `knapsack[capacity][dimension]`.

Comment: Do you have a sample dataset for us to try?